# Angular 8/9 How do I get the innerHTML of multiple elements with the same class name?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular8, angular9

I have a div that will be created as many times as I specify, basing off of the length of a variable called `totalQuestionsList`. I want to select the `innerHTML` of all the `<h5>` elements inside each div.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of totalQuestionsList; let i = index">
  <h5 class="question-num">Question #{{i+1}}</h5>
</div>
```

How do I do this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "select"? Do you need to edit it on the component? Or display it in some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a reference variable and use ViewChildren

```
<div *ngFor="let item of totalQuestionsList; let i = index">
  <h5 #h class="question-num">Question #{{i+1}}</h5>
</div>

@ViewChildren('h') elements:QueryList<ElementRef>
```

You can also use a directive with selector class

```
@Directive({
    selector:'.question-num'
})
export class QuestionDirective{
     constructor(public elementRef:ElementRef){}
}
```

And use

```
 @ViewChildren(QuestionDirective) elements:QueryList<QuestionDirective> 
 //e.g. console.log(elements.first.elementRef)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the ts file. Inject ElemementRef into the constructor

On that class there is a nativeElement.innerHtml  property

Use that to get your content